# How to align multiple line code in android studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-14

Constructor and function with many parameter(kotlin code) aligned in **a line**, that make the line is **too long** and hard to read. Even I put code in multiple line, it rerturned to one long line when I reformat(**ctrl+alt+l**). How to config in android studio to align long line code in to multiple lines or keep multiple lines when I reformat with (***ctrl+alt+l***)

[image]

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#class-header-formatting

Comment: @forpas your link is about coding convention, but I want to know how to config in android studio so that it accept multiple line constuctor, function when reformat with (ctrl+alt+l)